# How to add rental period attribute in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, product-attribute, configuration

**RENTING PERIOD:**

- How to add rental period attribute in Magento 2 ?
- So i can add price on Hourly and Daily Rental Period.

There will be product like daily based renting type which are used for days like the **vehicle**, **furniture**, and **home appliances**.

Like

1. Hire a car for the days you want to and get charged accordingly.
2. Hire Cloths for the days you want to and get charged accordingly.

[image]

Comment: You can create the custom option for particular product.You can select the radio as option type and add the price respectively for particular radio button value.

Comment: Actually my whole site is rental base, so it should be more fusible if i add product attribute of rental period. Any suggestion ?

Comment: @SunnyRahevar Please add an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use custom option like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This will take quite a bit of work to do. You'll need to add custom price calculations using a custom price model or a plugin.

If you use a plugin you could add an if statement to it that checks if the product has Date & Time custom options. You'll probably also want to add attributes for the daily and hourly rent price. If it does then you could override the price. I've never tried using this method though.

Our rental extension ( Sales Igniter https://rentalbookingsoftware.com ) uses this method instead which is to make a reservation product type. Code in your extension folder etc/product_types.xml file is like this:

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Catalog:etc/product_types.xsd">
    <type name="sirent" label="Reservation" modelInstance="SalesIgniter\Rental\Model\Product\Type\Sirent" composite="false" isQty="true" canUseQtyDecimals="false">
        <priceModel instance="SalesIgniter\Rental\Model\Product\Price"/>
</config>
```

Then the model at Model/Product/Price.php is like this (Please note I have removed the construct stuff and properties setup as well as the logic in the getFinalPrice method for brevity. You can start with what is at \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type\Price:

```
class Price extends \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type\Price
{

    public function __construct(
       
    ) {
       
    }

    
    public function getFinalPrice($qty, $product)
    {
        // code here to calculate price from custom attributes
        return $finalPrice;
    }
}
```

You will also need to add your Product Type model in Model/Product/Type/yourtype.php you can look at the Configurable or Bundle product types as examples in the base Magento 2 code.